# Python cannot find string in file when the string is just there

Tags: python, string, search

I have a database file "db.txt" in the format as follows:

```
"sg_number":1,"blablabala"....
"sg_number":2,"blablabala"....
"sg_number":10,"blablabala"....
"sg_number":9,"blablabala"....
```

and so on.

I want to delete all the lines that contains '"sg_number": i', for i in the range (1, 8) and output the remaining lines to another file "db_filtered.txt"

So I wrote the following code:

```
infile = open("db.txt", "r")

newopen = open('db_filtered.txt', 'w')

for i in range(1,8):
    a='"sg_number":'+ str(i) + ','
    for line in infile :
        if a in line:
            line = line.replace('.' , '')
        else:
            newopen.write(line)

newopen.close()
```

However, the generated db_filtered.txt still has everything in the db.txt. What I am expecting is for lines with "sg_number" less than 9 to be deleted.

What I noticed is that removing the "+ ','" in line 6 leads to deletion of any line that contains "sg_number":1 , which is line 1 and 3. But line 2 which satisfies the condition "i in range(1, 8)" is not deleted.

May I know what is wrong here and what corrections I should make for the code to do what it is supposed to do?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try to understand the code execution path, your code checks the whole file for each `i`, but it still **writes** to file if there is no match.

Answer (score 1):

```
new = infile.readlines() 
for line in new:
    for i in range(1,9):
        a='"sg_number":'+ str(i) + ','
        if a in line:
            new.remove(line)
```

This will create a new list with the lines removing "sg_number"1-8. Now write the list into the file.
I'm not quite sure but this will work.